# Edit comment works only for first comment

Tags: php, database, laravel

I had a different page for edit comments - `comments/{$id}/edit` and I'm trying to add this to a modal in the same page with my comment.The problem is , when I open my modal, I get only first comment of 5, even if I have buttons on all comments.What's happening here?

**My view + modal**

```
 <div class="col-md-12">


          @foreach($post->comments()->latest()->paginate(5) as $comment)

            <div class="media g-mb-30">
  <img class="d-flex g-width-50 g-height-50 rounded-circle g-mt-3 g-mr-20" src="/storage/{{ $comment->image }}" alt="Image Description">
  <div class="media-body g-brd-around g-brd-gray-light-v4 g-pa-30" style="margin-right: -35px">
    <div class="g-mb-15">
      <h5 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center h5 g-color-gray-dark-v1 mb-0">
        <span class="d-block g-mr-10">{{ $comment->username }}
         <span class="g-color-black-opacity-0_7 g-pos-rel g-top-2 mx-2">&#183;</span>
<span class="g-color-gray-dark-v4 g-font-size-12">{{ $comment->created_at }}</span>
       </span>
        <a class="u-tags-v1 g-font-size-12 g-brd-around g-brd-gray-light-v4 g-bg-primary--hover g-brd-primary--hover g-color-black-opacity-0_8 g-color-white--hover rounded g-py-6 g-px-15" href="/profile/{{ $comment->user_id }}">Author</a>
      </h5>
    </div>


    <p>{{$comment->comment}}</p>

    <ul class="list-inline d-sm-flex my-0">
        @can('update', $post->user->profile)
      <li class="list-inline-item ml-auto">
        <a href="#" class="u-link-v5 g-color-gray-dark-v4 g-color-primary--hover"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">
          <i class="icon-note g-pos-rel g-top-1 g-mr-3"></i>
          Edit comment
        </a>
         <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">



<div class="col-md-8 colm-d-offset-2">
<h1>edit comment</h1>
{{ Form::model($comment, ['route' => ['comments.update', $comment->id] , 'method' => 'PUT']) }}

 {{ Form::label('comment', "Comment:") }}
 {{ Form::textarea('comment', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

  {{ Form::submit('Update Comment', ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-xs']) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
</div>


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
      </li>
<li class="list-inline-item ml-auto">
        <a class="u-link-v5 g-color-gray-dark-v4 g-color-primary--hover" href="/deleteComment/{{$comment->id}}">
          <i class="icon-note g-pos-rel g-top-1 g-mr-3"></i>
          Delete comment
        </a>
      </li>
      @endcan
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


          @endforeach
            {{ $post->comments()->latest()->paginate(5)->links() }}


        </div>
      </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here is my old route :  **

```
Route::get('/comments/{id}/edit', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@edit', 'as' => 'comments.edit']);
```

**My controller**

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $comment = Comment::find($id);
        return view ('comments.edit')->withComment($comment);
    }

public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $comment = Comment::find($id);

        $this->validate($request, array('comment' => 'required'));

        $comment->comment = $request->comment;
        $comment->save();

        Session::flash('success', 'Comment updated');


        return redirect('/post/' . $comment->post->id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you must set `id="{!! $comment->id !!}`

```
   <a id="{!! $comment->id !!}" href="#" class="u-link-v5 g-color-gray-dark-v4 g-color-primary--hover"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">
      <i class="icon-note g-pos-rel g-top-1 g-mr-3"></i>
      Edit comment
    </a>
```

and if you want access to id by `$(this).attr("id");` and send this to modal or ajaxController

Comment: Ok, with `{{ $comment->id }}` I have right id  at hover on `edit comment`, but in my modal I have same comment, just first comment.Maybe is something wrong with my form from modal?

Comment: You must pass the id Comment to the Edit form(modal in ```{{ Form::model($comment, ['route' => ['comments.update', $comment->id] , 'method' => 'PUT']) }}```  )
This is not done now and the last comment is set

Comment: I have this line in my form from modal...but this returns me only first comment.I really appreciate if you will help me with that :)